# Putting Multiple conditions using np.where on python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
load = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,0],
                   'D':[1,3,5,4,2,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})
```

**I need check `b>c` where `c=d` and both `c,d!=0` if condition satisfy I need to put True else False.**

Output

```
False
False
False
True
True
False
```

Comment: Added timings to my answer, `apply` is `250 times` slowier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
load['print'] = load.apply(lambda x:(x.B>x.C)&(x.C==x.D)&(x.C!=0)&(x.D!=0),axis=1)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  print
0  a  4  7  1  5  a  False
1  b  5  8  3  3  a  False
2  c  4  9  5  6  a  False
3  d  5  4  4  9  b   True
4  e  5  2  2  2  b   True
5  f  4  0  0  4  b  False
```

or

```
load['print'] = np.where((load.B>load.C)&(load.C==load.D)&(load.C!=0)&(load.D!=0),True, False)
```

Comment: @YogeshSP try again

Comment: `apply` + `lambda` not recommended here, inefficient and anti-Pandas. `np.where`  is not required as Boolean series already consist of only `True` / `False` values.

Comment: @jpp You're right. `apply` +`lambda` inefficient here. Because `np.where` is required to output false by question, so I do it. If I can, use `(load.B>load.C)&(load.C==load.D)&(load.C!=0)&(load.D!=0)` directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think need chaining boolean mask by `&` for `bitwise AND`:

```
m = load.B.gt(load.C) & load.C.eq(load.D) & load[['C','D']].ne(0).any(axis=1)
#alternative
m = load.B.gt(load.C) & load.C.eq(load.D) & load['C'].ne(0) & load['D'].ne(0)

print (m)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

If want `numpy.where` get same output:

```
load['new'] = np.where(m, True, False)
print (load)
   A  B  C  D  E  F    new
0  a  4  7  1  5  a  False
1  b  5  8  3  3  a  False
2  c  4  9  5  6  a  False
3  d  5  4  4  9  b   True
4  e  5  2  2  2  b   True
5  f  4  0  0  4  b  False
```

It is used if need set 2 values by condition like:

```
load['new'] = np.where(m, 10, 20)
print (load)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  new
0  a  4  7  1  5  a   20
1  b  5  8  3  3  a   20
2  c  4  9  5  6  a   20
3  d  5  4  4  9  b   10
4  e  5  2  2  2  b   10
5  f  4  0  0  4  b   20
```

**Performance**:

```
load = pd.concat([load] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [106]: %timeit load['print'] = load.apply(lambda x:(x.B>x.C)&(x.C==x.D)&(x.C!=0)&(x.D!=0),axis=1)
408 ms ± 13.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [107]: %timeit load['print'] = load.B.gt(load.C) & load.C.eq(load.D) & load['C'].ne(0) & load['D'].ne(0)
1.64 ms ± 135 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.logical_and.reduce` with a tuple of Boolean series:

```
m1 = load['B'] > load['C']
m2 = load['C'] == load['D']
m3 = load['C'] != 0
m4 = load['D'] != 0

res = load[np.logical_and.reduce((m1, m2, m3, m4))]

print(res)

   A  B  C  D  E  F
3  d  5  4  4  9  b
4  e  5  2  2  2  b
```